# Time auto refresh

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel on a work laptop (Surface Pro) via Microsoft Teams and functionality is massively reduced.

I need to create a time function that auto updates (I was thinking of using an external data connection) the time in a hh:mm format without a user input.  I cannot add Macros to the spreadsheet.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does the solution work on surface? (Surface OEM fan here..)

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA macros, using data query connection, assume your sheet has a cell contain `NOW()` formula.

By Making connection with the same sheet for that cell, connection is allowed to be updated at least each one minute.

With this steps you can get table(with one cell) contain time value with one minute updating:

1. Go to Data ribbon tab then get data->from other sources->from table/range.
2. Select the cell that contain `NOW()` formula then ok.
3. Click `Close & Load` in Query editor window.
4. Table will be created with time value (you can move this table to whatever you want).
5. Select that table and go to Query contextual ribbon tab.
6. Open `Connection properties` from `External Table Data` section in Refresh's menu.
7. Check `refresh every` option and set the number of minutes.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: I I’m looking at connection from other sources and I’m not seeing table/range. 

The options I have are: from SQL server, from analysis services, from windows azure marketplace, from odata data feed, from xml data import, from data connection wizard, from Microsoft query.

Comment: What is the office version you are working with?

Comment: `table/range` is available from 2016 version.